# How to add multiple user metadata as order metadata in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I've created two custom user profile fields which I also use as user meta data. When an order is created, I need this information to be saved as order metadata in Woocommerce.

I've created a function for each instance.

For the VAT Number:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'wwp_customer_meta_data', 10, 2 );
function wwp_customer_meta_data( $order, $data ) {
    $user_id  = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id
    $wwp_vat = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wwp_wholesaler_tax_id', true );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'VAT Number', $wwp_vat );
}
```

For the Company Number in my accounting software:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'visma_customer_meta_data', 10, 2 );
function visma_customer_meta_data( $order, $data ) {
    $user_id  = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id
    $billing_visma = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_visma', true );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'Billing Visma', $billing_visma );
}
```

How do I combine both functions into a single function?

I want to learn how to create code more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_customer_meta_data_to_order', 10, 2 );

function visma_customer_meta_data( $order, $data ) {

    $user_id  = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id

    $billing_visma = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_visma', true );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'Billing Visma', $billing_visma );

    $wwp_vat = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wwp_wholesaler_tax_id', true );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'VAT Number', $wwp_vat );

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just had to updated the function name but works perfectly...